# Regex to detect single ' only and exclude two ''

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to make sure that there are no single `'` characters in a string. Therefore I'm looking for a regex that finds all single `'` characters. Two `''` must not match.

```
'adsfadsf''asdfasdf'asdfasfd''  ==> two machtes
''adsfadsf''asdfasdf''asdfasfd'' ==> no match
```

I tried different things, but all match some of the `''`.

```
'{1}
'[^']
'(?!')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What *flavor* of regex? It matters (some have negative lookahead/lookbehind, some don't). And what do you want to do with the results? (That can also matter, in terms of a pragmatic solution in the situations where you can't do it just with the regex because you don't have negative lookbehind.)

Comment: Could you give more background to this problem? Why do you have to do this?

Comment: Negative look-ahead with additional matching at the start and end of the subject, i.e. `^''` or `''$`.

Comment: Okay, the edit addresses **half** of the feedback. Again: What do you want to do with the results?

Comment: Nothing. If I get no machtes, the string is fine, otherwise the user get's an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below lookaround based regex.

```
(?<!')'(?!')
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE1fJ0/3)

If you're running javascript then you could try the below regex. But it would capture also the previous character, i think it won't create any problem for you.

```
(^|[^'])(')(?!')
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE1fJ0/4)

Get the matched single quote from group index 2.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, that I need the regex for javascript. Lookbehind, *SKIP or *F are not supported by javascript.

Comment: @BetaRide that's the reason crowder asked at very first. Why you failed to interact at the mean time?